# EF Code First table naming issues

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a project built using EF code first. It also uses forms authentication. Until recently the membership database and the application database were being developed separately, but I want to combine them into one database for simplicity.

One of the classes in my code first model is called "Application" so the EF-generated table is called "Applications" which conflicts with a membership table of the same name. This is an example of my current context:

```
public partial class ExampleContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Application> Applications { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Status> StatusTypes { get; set; } // notice the name of the property vs the name of the class
}
```

I thought the table names were based on the names of the properties in the context, because it was generating a table named `StatusTypes` for all of the `Status` objects. But if I rename the `Applications` property to something like `MyApplications` it is still generating a table named `Applications`. So clearly it's not just the name of the property and I'm missing something.

My question: how do I get EF to name this table differently?

Comment: Are you using a Web Site project or a web application project?  Web Site projects typically have these kinds of problems because they don't use namespaces to differentiate naming scopes.

Comment: The front end of the application is an MVC project. But all entity framework and other database operations are in a separate class library. Why would being a web application cause EF to name something differently? That doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: namespace.. not name.  A namespace provides a "scope" in which the name is valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just renamed the class and it worked. Easiest solution for now.

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you use the configuration class to do something like this:

```
public class ApplicationConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Application>
{
    public ClientConfiguration()
    {
        ToTable("SpecialApplication");
    }
}
```

Then in your context override OnModelCreating:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ApplicationConfiguration());
    }
```

This should then force your table to be named SpecialApplication and avoid the conflict

Answer (score 0):

By default, Entity framework code first will generate pluralized names for tables when it builds the db from the model classes. You can override the `OnModelCreating` method of your db context class specify a different name for the table.

```
public class YourDBCOntext:DbContext
{
  protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
  {
    modelBuilder.Entity<Applications>().ToTable("MYApplications");
  }    
}
```

You can do this globally also so that none of the tables will have pluralized names.

```
  protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
  {
     modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTaleNameConvention>();
  }    
}
```