# MVC5 Code first EF table name change

Tags: c#, entity-framework, model-view-controller

Can anyone tell me where the Metadata for a table reference is stored in MVC?

I had a problem with MVC creating tables with an s on the end of the ones that existed in the database and I had defined.

Found this which explains the reason because of pluralization: [EF Code First table naming issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12939091/ef-code-first-table-naming-issues)

So added that code to remove the pluralization issue then got the error saying the definition had changed and to consider using code first migration.

Run the Enable-Migrations, Add-Migration SiteMenu and then Update-Database at which point I had an error saying it could not create the table as it already exists.

So even though every reference in my code points to SiteMenu I can't actually reference the table because when I first tried to run it VS has created some sort of metaData reference to say it is called SiteMenu**S**

How can I access this?

Just seems horrendously bad that you create a model class the defines your table, and yet any changes to that require you to run console code to update some reference file that you don't have clear access to.

Is there an alternative to this where I can build and maintain my own references?

Comment: I generally, instead of doing migrations I delete the database in using SQL Management Studio, I set automatic migrations to true. Then i just use UpdateDatabase -Verbose -Force

Comment: I can't just delete an existing production database every time I want to make a reference change to a table.

Comment: Sorry, I must have missed the part where you said it was in production.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for information on how to access the metadata that is created.

Comment: have you by any chance looked on [asp.net](http://www.asp.net) they have a lot of information on how to do migrations.